# Commit Dataset to database after changing row in C# - ERROR

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, dataset, commit

I need some help.

I am trying to update the changes made to a `DataSet` -> `DataTable` ->`DataRow` to the database, but i get the following error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: Error from UpdateConsumer:  ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

First i get a DataSet from a database after certain criteria, i change a value from a DataRow and after i update the changes to the db.

Here is the code:

```
DataSet data = new exampleClass().getConsumer(WebId, UserID);
DataTable firstTable = data.Tables[0];
DataRow firstRow = firstTable.Rows[0];

firstRow["Password"] = new_password;
firstTable.AcceptChanges();
bool success = new exampleClass().updateConsumer(data);
```

When i try to update the consumer, i get the error that i pointed out. The updateConsumer() method has a DataSet type parameter.

Could anyone help? Why is this error occurring?

Best regards, Marius.

Comment: Can you show `updateConsumer` function code?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because it's on the clients side and we don't have access to the code behind. But i solved my problem...i used another function from their part and now it seems to be working.